# Encrypted FTP Storage

Tags: ftp, backup-strategies

I guess this is kind of a programming question, because I'm going to write a program if this doesn't exist.

So I found a very cheap web-host (I don't really care about the actual web hosting). They will give me a domain name and ftp server with a ton of storage space. Anyway, I want to backup a few hundred gigs of data (mostly family photos and scans of important documents). I also want to backup any future family photos / documents. I don't care if everything on my local NAS dies in a fire, I just want to have the photos and important documents backed up off-site.

So I want some program that lets me select folders locally and schedules them to be backed up to the ftp server. I'm a bit of a security nut, so i'd like the files to be encrypted locally before being transferred up onto the server.

I know I can do this with truecrypt volumes, but I don't want to transfer an entire encrypted volume blob up to the server ever time I change a file in it. So I could do multiple true crypt volumes but that will be a pain to manage

Also this must be mac/linux compatible although I'll primarily be on linux.

I basically need rsync + truecrypt + cron + sftp all rolled into a cryptographically secure program.

I've been searching for days with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like this could be put together as a shell script quite easily, though I guess a shell script does not count as a "cryptographically secure program".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mozyBackup](http://mozy.com) does this - it doesn't use FTP, it has a custom uploader.

ps. Remember a typical home ADSL connection only does about 1Gb/day upstream

Linux option.
Out of the box option probably [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/index.html) ( for example see http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-encrypted-ftp-backups-with-duplicity-and-ftplicity-on-debian-lenny )
Otherwise if these are basically rarely changed archive copies of files - I would roll my own gnupg (or dpad) individual file encryption, a file changed script, and ftp or rsync.

Comment: Speed isn't really an issue. I don't care if it takes 3 months to get everything up there. Just that it gets there. Mozy seems to be mac/windows only. I also found carbonite, but same problem: only win/mac.